# Spring Hibernate Integration Example executes even when value of driverclassname and hibernate dialect is wrong

Tags: spring, hibernate, hsqldb

In this tutorial on Spring

http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-hibernate-integration-1.html

when MySQL is used instead of HSQL, with Spring Bean Configuration file including datasource URL, password, username and

```
  driverclassname and hibernate Dialect are changed to MySQL values accordingly.
```

The example executes successfully. But even when

```
      driverclassname and hibernate Dialect are changed back to HSQL values,
```

even then this program executes...

Should it not show error?
I am using Spring Tool Suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the HSQL database is an in memory database which is embedded in your example. So if you provides correct information and executes successfully your code against `mysql` database, nothing forbid you to execute the same code using another Database and especially `HSQL DB`.

Moreover, knowing this, you can use HSQL DB for automated integration tests because it executes fast.

Comment: Hey Thanks benzonico, But could you kindly let me know why after using hsqldb driverclassname and hsql dialectname, the example was still capable of connecting to my mysql database. I started mysql database through command line and the program was still changing my mysql database. Thanks a lot, dear friend.

Comment: That's probably because you did not execute the updated configuration in some way.

Comment: I restarted Spring multiple times and even switched my workspace and even created the same example thrice from scratch. Thanks a ton for answering, friend...